# Python table output in IPAC style

Tags: python, tabular

I'd like to make an IPAC output table (http://docs.astropy.org/en/v0.2.1/table/io.html)

I have two data columns, ra and dec, and these are two numpy arrays::

```
type(data['ra'])
numpy.ndarray
```

However,

```
data_out = (data['ra'], data['dec'])
data_out.write('data_out.tbl', format='ipac')
```

but then get:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: You can't write a tuple directly to a file

Comment: Okay; so what *should* I do??!!

Comment: You can use pickle for your purpose but the file extension will be .pickle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from astropy.table import Table
data_out = Table.from_pandas(data)
output_path = '/data_out.tbl'

# Write the table in IPAC format
data_out.write(output_path, format='ipac')
```